# IWorkbenchListener type resolving error

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to write an eclipse plugin which adds a WorkbenchListener. I used the methods provided in the accepted answer to this question: 
[Eclipse shut down hook able to stop the termination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579716/eclipse-shut-down-hook-able-to-stop-the-termination). 
But `iwb.addWorkbenchListener(wbl);` throws the error: 

`The type org.eclipse.core.runtime.IAdaptable cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means the plug-in containing the listener depends on another plug-in containing `IAdaptable`. To fix this add the `org.eclipse.core.runtime` plug-in to your plug-in dependencies (this is the plug-in that contains `IAdaptable`).