# Executing eclipse plugin automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I try to create an eclipse plugin which deletes some files when eclipse workbench is closed. I started with the `Hello, World command` plugin project and added a `IWorkbenchListener` like mentioned in this toppic [Eclipse shut down hook able to stop the termination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579716/eclipse-shut-down-hook-able-to-stop-the-termination). The listener is added when I press a special button in the eclipse menu bar (which is added by this plugin).

How can I automatically add this `IWorkbenchListener`, without the need of clicking on any menu entry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point to specify a class that implements `org.eclipse.ui.IStartup`. This will be called early on during Eclipse initialization.

So in the `plugin.xml`:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.startup">
  <startup
        class="your class implementing IStartup"/>
</extension>
```

Class:

```
public class Startup implements IStartup
{
  @Override
  public void earlyStartup()
  {
    // you action
  }
}
```