# Eclipse plugin not executed

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I wrote an eclipse plugin which should be executed at startup of workspace (see [Executing eclipse plugin automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660136/executing-eclipse-plugin-automatically)). It works perfectly when I try it out with the Run button. But now I created an update site and installed the plugin via the update manager. I don't know why but now it is not executed when eclipse workspace starts.

What could be the problem here?

Content of `plugin.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.startup">
       <startup class="plugin.first.handlers.StartClass"/>
    </extension>
</plugin>
```

I found some additional info in `/workspace/.metadata/.log`:

```
!SESSION 2014-02-10 14:17:08.358 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
java.version=1.7.0_02
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2014-02-10 14:17:21.380
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils
    at plugin.first.handlers.ClearFolder.doClear(ClearFolder.java:12)
    at plugin.first.handlers.StartClass.earlyStartup(StartClass.java:15)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2551)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils cannot be found by plugin.clearsvnauth_1.0.0.201402101022
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-02-10 14:17:21.393
!MESSAGE Unhandled Exception

!ENTRY plugin.clearsvnauth 4 0 2014-02-10 14:17:21.394
!MESSAGE Unable to execute early startup code for an extension
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils
    at plugin.first.handlers.ClearFolder.doClear(ClearFolder.java:12)
    at plugin.first.handlers.StartClass.earlyStartup(StartClass.java:15)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2551)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils cannot be found by plugin.clearsvnauth_1.0.0.201402101022
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Why do I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`?

Comment: Check that the `plugin.xml` is included in the code.

Comment: `plugin.xml` is included in the project. I have posted its content in my question.

Comment: Probabky a dependency is missing. Do you see anything in the `workspace/.metadata/log`? How about the content of the installed plugin, is it complete?

Comment: Most of the time, people lack something in their ´build.properties´ file or defined something in the Run-Configuration instead of a product file.
Did you think about using the touch point instruction of a product instead? http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/06/10/osgi-and-start-levels/
With definitions in your product, it's harder to miss out on something.

Comment: It seems that there is really something missing in build-configuration. See the log posted in my question. How do I configure my project correctly for build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself. You need to add jars you used in your project to your build configuration (see attached picture).

[image: Build Configuration]