# How to display gef editor?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

I am trying to use GEF for displaying and editing a flow diagram in an RCP. I have used `GraphicalEditorWithFlyoutPalette` as my editor looking at various examples on the internet. I n all those examples I dont find tips on how to show this editor when my RCP application starts first. previously I used a ViewPart to display the flow diagram and it worked fine. Now I am struck without knowing how to open the same on the editor which I designed.

Comment: You could use the startup extension point to open the editor: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21660164/2670892

Comment: Is this equivalent of `showView` method for a ViewPart ? or How can I programatically open the `GraphicalEditor` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IDE` class has several methods for opening an editor, for example:

```java
IFile file = ... file you want to open

IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

IEditorInput input = new FileEditorInput(file);

IDE.openEditor(page, input, "editor id");
```

You can use the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point to run code early in the Eclipse start up but the code above will not run so early in the start up. But you can schedule a `UIJob` to run the code:

```java
@Override
public void earlyStartup()
{
  new StartJob().schedule();
}


class StartJob extends UIJob
{
  public StartJob()
  {
    super("Start Job");
  }

  @Override
  public IStatus runInUIThread(final IProgressMonitor monitor)
  {
    .. open editor code   

    return Status.OK_STATUS;
  }
}
```